# Error handling of Databin

Tags: error-tracking, form-building, databin

I am using Databin in a FormFunction and would like to check whether the `DatabinAdd[]` was successful. If it is not I get a \$Failed but I am unable to check for it. Opening the non existing Databin `err = Databin["13X7XXXJH"]` will result in an error and the output Failed. As expected. Using `FailureQ[err]` gives however the wrong result False.

```
err === $Failed
```

Results also in False, while

```
err == $Failed
```

Results in \$Failed == \$Failed.

How can I check whether a Databin command has been successful?

Answer (score 1):

`Databin` does not evaluate when the bin does not exist. Calling it with an invalid id

```
err = Databin["13X7XXXJH"]
```

does not result in `err=$Failure` as one might expect but rather remains unevaluated as `Databin["13X7XXXJH"]` and calling `err` again results in the at this point already issued error message. For checking validity of a bin this is as discovered in this question rather unpleasant. I tried using `Check`, `FailureQ`, *etc.* without success.  To be honest I am not sure if `Databin` is implemented correctly/properly in this regard because the output after `Databin::apierr` strongly suggests `err=$Failure`.

I proceed by looking under the hood of `Databin` using `PrintDefinitions` from the `GeneralUtilities` package and I found the subroutine which checks id strings for validity:

```
err=Catch@DataDropClient`Private`getBinID["13X7XXXJH"]
```

evaluates to `$Failed` with the specific error message `Databin::nobin`. Using `getBinID` one can define

```
DatabinCheck[s_String]:=Catch@Quiet[DataDropClient`Private`getBinID[s],Databin::nobin]
```

which returns a complete UUID string if `s` is the id of an existing Databin and `$Failed` (without printing and error message) if `s` is invalid. One might use `StringQ` or `FailureQ` on the result to check it. Another option would be to use something like

```
DatabinCheck[s_String]:=Quiet[Check[Catch@DataDropClient`Private`getBinID[s],failexpr,Databin::nobin],Databin::nobin]
```

to return (or call) `failexpr` directly from within `DatabinCheck`.

Using the internal method `getBinID` might introduce some overhead and might not be very robust (given that it is an internal function which might/is change/d in future/past versions). Catching the `Databin::apierr` thrown by `Databin` itself seems much more elegant but I could not get this to work as discussed earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I suspect that FailureQ not working is a bug with Databin. I don't think I can use internals as the form is deployed to the cloud. I will try however.